# Singleton INotifyPropertyChanged does not change after initial defining and binding

Tags: c#, wpf, singleton, inotifypropertychanged

So, I created a Singleton to be used to track a ToolTip enabler that is used globally throughout the entire application, but when I try to bind it to a ToolTip, it binds the value initially, but then when I change the ToolTip enabler value, the binding does not update.

This is the User Control that creates the bind to the ToolTip:

```
 public partial class ViewTreeClass : UserControl {
      private void addStuff() {
           EnvironmentalVariables.Instance.ToolTipEnable = true;
           Binding bind = new Binding() {
                Source = EnvironmentalVariables.Instance.ToolTipEnable,
           };
           ToolTip x = new ToolTip();
           x.Content = "This is text";
           user.SetBinding(ToolTipService.IsEnabledProperty, bind);
           user.ToolTip = x;
           EnvironmentalVariables.Instance.ToolTipEnable = false;
           // Executing the above statement changes the variable, but ToolTipService.IsEnabledProperty does not change to reflect EnvironmentalVariables.Instance.ToolTipEnable
      }
 }
```

This is the Singleton that implements INotifyPropertyChanged:

```
 public class EnvironmentalVariables : INotifyPropertyChanged {
      private static EnvironmentalVariables instance = new EnvironmentalVariables();
      public static EnvironmentalVariables Instance {
           get {
                if(instance == null) {
                     instance = new EnvironmentalVariables();
                }
                return instance;
           }
      }

      private EnvironmentalVariables() { }

      private bool tooltipEnable;
      public bool ToolTipEnable {
           get {
                return tooltipEnable;
           }
           set {
                if(tooltipEnable != value) {
                     tooltipEnable = value;
                     this.RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged("ToolTipEnable");
                }
           }
      }

      private void RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged(string property) {
           if(PropertyChanged != null) {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
           }
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 }
```

When I change 'EnvironmentalVariables.Instance.ToolTipEnable = false;' it changes the Singleton variable to 'false', but it doesn't update ToolTipService.EnabledProperty to 'false' and PropertyChanged is always null. Am I missing a subscription to PropertyChanged somewhere?

The Singleton and the UC are both in different namespaces/class files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem is in the first extract IMO, the way you create the binding. What type is `user` ?

Set `Instance` as the Source, and `ToolTipEnable` as the Path (`bind.Path = new PropertyPath("ToolTipEnable")`).

And have you a reason for using `ToolTipService.IsEnabledProperty` instead of `ToolTip.IsEnabledProperty` ? I'm not sure this is the good place for this trick (but I may be wrong, try both ^^).

Your singleton is wrong (but not causing the problem). I've corrected the way you raise your event too :

```
 public sealed class EnvironmentalVariables : INotifyPropertyChanged {
      private static readonly EnvironmentalVariables instance = new EnvironmentalVariables();
      public static EnvironmentalVariables Instance {
           get 
           {
               return instance;
           }
      }

      private EnvironmentalVariables() { }

      private bool tooltipEnable;
      public bool ToolTipEnable {
           get {
                return tooltipEnable;
           }
           set {
                if(tooltipEnable != value) {
                     tooltipEnable = value;
                     this.RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged("ToolTipEnable");
                }
           }
      }

      private void RaiseNotifyPropertyChanged(string property) {
           var handler = PropertyChanged;
           if(handler != null) {
                handler (this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
           }
      }

      public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
 }
```

Comment: About the event, have a look here : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/04/29/events-and-races.aspx

Comment: That article is an amazing read. Is there a reason you're using 'var handler' instead of 'PropertyChangedEventHandler handler' or is it just for short-hand?

Comment: I used 'ToolTipService.IsEnabledProperty' because ToolTip.IsEnabledProperty' doesn't seem to exist, or at least that's what VS2010 is telling me. Either way, it works now. :D

Comment: Eric Lippert's blog is an amazing read, I advice you to read it all, it worth it ;)

Comment: `var` is a type inference keyword, it says to the compiler "go ahead, guess the type by yourself, you have enough informations here". Don't mistake with dynamic though.

Answer (score 1):

I believe it has to do with not setting the `DataContext` of your `ViewTreeClass` since I don't really see any other errors with the code. Try setting the `DataContext` to the singleton class at the beginning of your `addStuff()` method. Also, although tangential to your question, I would really suggest doing what you're doing in the partial class in the control's XAML since creating the binds programatically is usually pretty messy.